# How the wave functions of large molecules behaves in the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I recently saw an article which described how researchers had gotten a molecule with hundreds of atoms to preform the the double slit experiment and confirmed that even structures of that size had could have wave functions which are large enough to cause an interference pattern. My question is at what point does the wave like behavior of large molecules decrease to the point that it is negligible? Is there some function that describes the inverse relationship between the a molecules mass and its associated wave function? Also, does the wave function of large molecules change depending on the structure of the molecule and center of mass of the molecule? Sorry if any of this question appears ignorant. My formal physics education is lacking.

Comment: Yes it becomes negligible, i.e. there is no detector with fine enough resolution to detect at the very small pattern that larger masses make. You can search this site as I remember someone doing the math for a similar question... All these patterns are due to interaction with the EM field, the particle's mass sets the wavelength ... you don't need a wave function, the Heisenberg equation is enough to give you the pattern spacing.